# Bash & (ampersand) operator

Tags: bash, background-process, exit-code

I'm trying to run 3 commands in parallel in bash shell:

```
$ (first command) & (second command) & (third command) & wait
```

The problem with this is that if `first command` fails, for example, the exit code is `0` (I guess because `wait` succeeds).

The desired behavior is that if one of the commands fails, the exit code will be non-zero (and ideally, the other running commands will be stopped).

How could I achieve this?

Please note that I want to run the commands in parallel!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the best I can think of is:

```
first & p1=$!
second & p2=$!
...

wait $p1 && wait $p2 && ..
```

or

```
wait $p1 || ( kill $p2 $p3 && exit 1 )
...
```

however this still enforces an order for the check of processes, so if the third fails immediately you won't notice it until the first and second finishes.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
parallel -j3 --halt 2 <list_of_commands.txt
```

This will run 3 commands in parallel.

If any running job fails it will kill the remaining running jobs and then stop, returning the exit code of the failing job.

Comment: It will run 3 commands in parallel but won't meet the exit code requirement of OP.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko google gnu parallel. @anubhava from the parallel manual `--halt 2  Kill off all jobs immediately and exit without cleanup. The exit status will be the exit status from the failing job.`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&&` instead of `&`. eg:

```
first command && second command && third command && wait
```

However this will NOT run your command in parallel as every subsequent command's execution will depend on exit code 0 of the previous command.

Comment: I think that would work in terms of return code, but won't execute the commands in parallel.

Comment: Agreed and made a note in my answer as well. However if commands are running in parallel then you cant check for exit code because previous command hasn't exited when 2nd one runs.

Comment: The main constraint here is to run the commands **in parallel**. I don't mind to replace this one-liner with more complicated bash script as long as the commands will run in parallel and the exit code will be non-zero in case of failures.

Comment: Pls understand that if commands are running in parallel (or in background) then you cannot have exit status immediately available, you will have to wait until commands exit.

Answer (score 0):

The shell function below will wait for all PIDs passed as arguments to finish, returning 0 if all PIDs executed without error.

The first PID that exists with an error will cause the PIDs that come after it to be killed, and the exit code that caused the error will be returned by the function.

```
wait_and_fail_on_first() {
  local piderr=0 i
  while test $# -gt 0; do {
    dpid="$1"; shift
    wait $dpid || { piderr=$?; kill $@; return $piderr ;}
  } done
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
(first command) & pid1=$!
(second command) & pid2=$!
(third command) & pid3=$!

wait_and_fail_on_first $pid1 $pid2 $pid3 || {
  echo "PID $dpid failed with code $?"
  echo "Other PIDs were killed"
}
```