# How to speed up / parallelize downloads of git submodules using git clone --recursive?

Tags: git, performance, download, git-submodules, git-clone

Cloning git repositories that have a lot submodules takes a really long time. In the following example are ~100 submodules

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix
```

Git clones them one by one. Takes much longer than required. Let's make the (probable) assumption that both the client and the server has sufficient resources to answer multiple (parallel) requests at the same time.

How to speed up / parallelize downloads of git submodules using `git clone --recursive`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316257/git-submodule-init-async

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17322442/2605155

Comment: With Git 2.8 (Q1 2016), you will be able to fetch submodules in parallel (!) with `git fetch --recurse-submodules -j2`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34762036/6309)

Comment: @adrelanos You may wish to consider changing your accepted answer to the one which references the now built-in Git option.

Comment: I am using git 2.17.1 and none of the answers works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I run your command it takes 338 seconds wall-time for downloading the 68 Mb.

With the following Python program that relies on GNU parallel to be installed,

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function

import os
import subprocess

jobs=16

modules_file = '.gitmodules'

packages = []

if not os.path.exists('Whonix/' + modules_file):
    subprocess.call(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix'])

os.chdir('Whonix')

# get list of packages from .gitmodules file
with open(modules_file) as ifp:
    for line in ifp:
        if not line.startswith('[submodule '):
            continue
        package = line.split(' "', 1)[1].split('"', 1)[0]
        #print(package)
        packages.append(package)

def doit():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['parallel', '-N1', '-j{0}'.format(jobs),
                          'git', 'submodule', 'update', '--init',
                          ':::'],
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    res = p.communicate('\n'.join(packages))
    print(res[0])
    if res[1]:
        print("error", res[1])
    print('git exit value', p.returncode)
    return p.returncode

# sometimes one of the updates interferes with the others and generate lock
# errors, so we retry
for x in range(10):
    if doit() == 0:
        print('zero exit from git after {0} times'.format(x+1))
        break
else:
    print('could not get a non-zero exit from git after {0} times'.format(
          x+1))
```

that time is reduced to 45 seconds (on the same system, I did **not** do multiple runs to average out fluctuations).

To check if things were OK, I "compared" the checked out files with:

```sh
find Whonix -name ".git" -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > /tmp/md5.sum
```

in the one directory and

```sh
md5sum -c /tmp/md5sum
```

in the other directory and vice versa.

Comment: Once you have executed the clone command you will have problems with the speed of `git submodule foreach` command. For that porpose you can use [parallel foreach submodule](https://github.com/RDCH106/parallel_foreach_submodule).

You can take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50178665/9739532

Answer (score 41):

With git 2.8 (Q12016), you will be able to initiate the fetch of submodules... in parallel!

See [commit fbf7164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbf71645d12d30219e88598c4867ef7c2fe48cee) (16 Dec 2015) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
See [commit 62104ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62104ba14af4845c6c1ba1dab05fad4a289d806f), [commit fe85ee6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe85ee6e23e642985004d37e63b4c0d0e5f30587), [commit c553c72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c553c72eed64b5f7316ce227f6d5d783eae6f2ed), [commit bfb6b53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfb6b53c05daedc4084a5f716804a83781826230), [commit b4e04fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4e04fb66e87a027c5f9c96bcbbba50719400169), [commit 1079c4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1079c4be0b72003668df647f8a520fa137c7e158) (16 Dec 2015) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 187c0d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/187c0d3d9e63f7d84d7055372f07bedb52849f06), 12 Jan 2016)</sup>

> Add a framework to spawn a group of processes in parallel, and use
> it to run "`git fetch --recurse-submodules`" in parallel.

For that, `git fetch` has the new option:

```
-j, --jobs=<n>
```

> Number of parallel children to be used for fetching submodules.
> **Each will fetch from different submodules, such that fetching many submodules will be faster.**
> By default, submodules will be fetched one at a time.

Example:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules -j2
```

---

The bulk of this new feature is in [commit c553c72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c553c72eed64b5f7316ce227f6d5d783eae6f2ed) (16 Dec 2015) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).

> ### `run-command`: add an asynchronous parallel child processor

> **This allows to run external commands in parallel with ordered output on stderr**.
>
> If we run external commands in parallel we cannot pipe the output directly to the our stdout/err as it would mix up. So each process's output will flow through a pipe, which we buffer. One subprocess can be directly piped to out stdout/err for a low latency feedback to the user.

---

Note that, before Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), "`git fetch --jobs=<n>`" allowed `<n>` parallel jobs when fetching submodules, but this did not apply to "`git fetch --multiple`" that fetches from multiple remote repositories.
It now does.

See [commit d54dea7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d54dea77dba081770fec7707110d8480ccaf9439) (05 Oct 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d96e31e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d96e31e3902d615c03471c8566ce89872c3c1a4e), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d54dea77dba081770fec7707110d8480ccaf9439): let `--jobs=<n>` parallelize `--multiple`, too
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> So far, `--jobs=<n>` only parallelizes submodule fetches/clones, not `--multiple` fetches, which is unintuitive, given that the option's name does not say anything about submodules in particular.
>
> Let's change that.
> **With this patch, also fetches from multiple remotes are parallelized**.
>
> For backwards-compatibility (and to prepare for a use case where submodule and multiple-remote fetches may need different parallelization limits):
>
> - the config setting `submodule.fetchJobs` still only controls the submodule part of `git fetch`,
> - while the newly-introduced setting `fetch.parallel` controls both (but can be overridden for submodules with `submodule.fetchJobs`).

---

See also Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) and **[`git pull` multiple remotes in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75777980/6309)**, for a bug with `git fetch --jobs=0` fixed in that release.

Comment: Note: a git clone for a repo with submodule will always try to clone a submodule *twice* (one retry). See "[Is there any way to continue Git clone from the point where it failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38329327/6309)".