# git pull multiple remotes in parallel

Tags: git, github, concurrency, download

I have a repo with thousands of remotes, and I'd like to pull from thousands of remotes at the same time, ideally I can specify a maximum number to do at the same time.

I wasn't able to find anything related to this in the manpages, google, or git-scm online.

To be perfectly clear: I do not want to run one command over multiple repos, I have one repo with thousands of remotes.

This has nothing to do with submodules, don't talk about submodules. Submodules are unrelated to git remotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up / parallelize downloads of git submodules using git clone --recursive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023395/how-to-speed-up-parallelize-downloads-of-git-submodules-using-git-clone-recu)

Comment: No, this has nothing do do with submodules. This is about an entirely different feature of git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from Git [2.24](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.24.0.txt#L73-L75) it it [now possible](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d54dea77dba081770fec7707110d8480ccaf9439) with [`[--jobs]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---jobsltngt) option.

Some examples:

Fetching 3 remotes, 2 remotes will be fetched in parallel:

```
git fetch -j2 --multiple remote1 remote2 remote3
```

Fetching all remotes, 5 remotes will be fetched in parallel:

```
git fetch -jobs=5 --all
```

If you have thousands of remotes and you don't want to download all of them and they form some logical groups. Instead of specifying them in command line (with `--multiple`) options You can also define remote groups like this in .git/config

```
[remotes]
    group1 = remote1 remote2 origin
    group2 = remote55 remote66
```

And then use this group in fetch command.

This command: `git fetch --multiple -j4 group1 group2 remote10` fetches `remote1 remote2 origin remote55 remote66 remote10` remotes and 4 fetches are done in parallel.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you have to write your own code to do this.

As [CodeWizard says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019999/git-pull-multiple-remotes-in-parallel#comment73128694_43020251), Git needs to lock parts of the repository. Some of these locks are bound to collide at times, if you simply run multiple `git fetch` processes in parallel within a single repository.

You might also want some kind of remote-ordering strategy since, e.g., collecting from `remoteA`, `remoteB`, and `remoteC` in parallel may discover 10000 common objects on `remoteB` as compared to the other two if `remoteB` is generally (but not always) a superset of `remoteA` and `remoteC`.<sup>1</sup>  While this also applies to sequential `git fetch` operations, it becomes considerably less important.  Suppose, for example, that there are 5000 objects—some commits, some trees, and some blobs—on A that you do not yet have, 5000 others on C, and all 10000 on B.  If you fetch sequentially, in any order, you pick up either 5k, then 5k, then 0; or 10k, then 0, then 0; because by the time you move to the *next* remote, you have collected and stored the 5k or 10k incoming objects.  But if you do all three in parallel, you will bring 5k, 5k, and 10k objects in, and only *then* discover that you have doubled your workload.

---

<sup>1</sup>If B is *always* a superset, simply go to B first (sequentially), then go to A and C in parallel *solely for their references*, which will point to objects you now have.

Comment: What's nice about my specific issue is I know for a fact there are no common objects. However there is a strange thing to me about this... I thought git was event-sourcing commit objects. It seems to me in theory that it should be able to collect n-many commit refs and do the integrity map on them later. I think you're right that I may have to author my own solution here.

Comment: Even without common commits, there might still be common trees or blobs (although I would suspect it would be less, er, "common" :-) ). But with the no-common-commits guarantee, you might want to look into using `git bundle` behind the scenes, and then sequentially scanning (as in run `git fetch` on) completed bundles and updating metadata for the given remote.

Answer (score 1):

> `git pull` multiple remotes in parallel: Starting from Git 2.24, it it now possible with `[--jobs]` option.

Then make sure to use Git 2.40 (Q1 2023): "[`git fetch --jobs=0`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d180cc297922569e530da843bee4df3964167dea/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L219)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---jobsltngt))</sup> used to hit a BUG(), which has been corrected to use the available CPUs.

See [commit c39952b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c39952b925ccf59e49f3c174861a862dc1721492) (20 Feb 2023) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d180cc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d180cc297922569e530da843bee4df3964167dea), 24 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c39952b925ccf59e49f3c174861a862dc1721492): choose a sensible default with `--jobs=0` again
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Drew Noakes</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthias Aßhauer</sup>

> prior to [51243f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51243f9f0f6a932ea579fd6f8014b348f8c2a523) ("run-command API: don't fall back on `online_cpus()`", 2022-10-12, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ae1a6eaf2630365c8dd6f8764881b79ba6899ff) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5af5e54106e20f65c913550c80aec3186b859e9b)) [`git` fetch `--multiple` --jobs=0``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c39952b925ccf59e49f3c174861a862dc1721492/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L108)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---multiple))</sup> would choose some default amount of jobs, similar to [`git -c fetch.parallel=0 fetch --multiple`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c39952b925ccf59e49f3c174861a862dc1721492/Documentation/git.txt#L76)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt))</sup>.
> While our documentation only ever promised that `fetch.parallel` would fall back to a "sensible default", it makes sense to do the same for `--jobs`.
> So fall back to `online_cpus()` and not BUG() out.
>
> This fixes "**`--jobs=0` no longer does any work** ([`git-for-windows/git` issue 4302](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4302))"