# Fetching multiple Git remotes in parallel

Tags: git

In git, is it possible to fetch multiple remotes in parallel?

Would the below work without clashing with the git file locking in the repository.

```
git config gc.auto 0
git remote |xargs --max-procs=4 -n 1 git fetch
git gc
```

I had small test with several repositories and it seems to work when all repositories are unrelated to each other.

It would be nice to get feedback if there is a clear technical reason why the parallel fetching command above wouldn't work.

The submodule is supporting parallel fetching but the parallel fetching would be good when utilizing git-subtree approach.

Similar question: [git pull multiple remotes in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019999/git-pull-multiple-remotes-in-parallel])

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually *maybe*.  In particular:

> ```
> git remote | xargs --max-procs=4 -n 1 git fetch
> ```

As you've seen, this actually works when tested, up to a point.  I wrote a fancy version of the same kind of thing once (with fancy display control of the fetching process, all written in Python—it turns out that there's a bug in `git fetch --progress`, though, so that this does not work right with pipes; you must use ptys).

> without clashing with the git file locking ... it seems to work when all repositories are unrelated to each other.

That's the rub: each fetch assumes it can get its locks.  The fetches need to lock each remote-tracking name, and usually that works just fine since the names are separate—remote `A` does not interfere with remote `B` because `refs/remotes/A/master` and `refs/remotes/B/master` use different locks—but the final repacking may fail unless you do what you did, disable auto-`gc` and then run GC yourself (you should also re-renable it afterward).

You may also end up fetching more data than necessary (as I noted in the other answer).  There is not much you can do about this without external information, e.g., maybe there's one remote you should always fetch first.

Answer (score 1):

> but the final repacking may fail unless you do what you did, disable auto-gc and then run GC yourself

Actually, with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), that might not be necessary anymore.

"`git fetch`" that grabs from a group of remotes learned to run the
`auto-gc` only once at the very end.

See [commit c3d6b70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3d6b70338d0ac93f66142873f1606277dbe589f) (19 Jun 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 892d3fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/892d3fb71e75849811c038b9fcaf17188a9ccf5d), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: only run '`gc`' once when fetching multiple remotes
>
> In multiple remotes mode, `git-fetch` is launched for n-1 remotes and the last remote is handled by the current process. Each of these processes will in turn run '`gc`' at the end.
>
> This is not really a problem because even if multiple '`gc --auto`' is run
>   at the same time we still handle it correctly.
>   It does show multiple "auto packing in the background" messages though.
>   And we may waste some resources when `gc` actually runs because we still do some stuff before checking the lock and moving it to background.
>
> So let's try to avoid that.
>
> We should only need one '`gc`' run after all objects and references are added anyway.
>
> Add a new option `--no-auto-gc` that will be used by those `n-1` processes.
>   '`gc --auto`' will always run on the main fetch process (*).
>
> (*) even if we fetch remotes in parallel at some point in future, this should still be fine because we should "join" all those processes before this step.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me out of the box with

```
git fetch -j 8
```

using Git 2.33.1 . The `-j` switch is a shorthand for `--jobs`. I remember looking for this earlier but only found out today, the switch might be pretty new.

Some timings for a repo with four GitHub remotes:

```
$ \time git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching foo
Fetching bar
Fetching baz
        6.40 real         1.28 user         0.21 sys
$ \time git fetch --all -j 8
Fetching origin
Fetching foo
Fetching bar
Fetching baz
        2.06 real         1.30 user         0.16 sys
```

Comment: Please let others know why the switch is `-j`. It because this is in the manual: `-j` / `--jobs=<n>` *Number of parallel children to be used for all forms of fetching.*

Comment: What you did is not parallel. Per the docs: *If the `--multiple option` was specified, the different remotes will be fetched in parallel. (…) Typically, parallel recursive and multi-remote fetches will be faster. By default fetches are performed sequentially, not in parallel.* https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: Added the verbose option and timings.