# Callback based on exit status of command in bash shell scripting?

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have 10 commands executing in parallel:

```
comdA & comdB & comdC & comdD
```

…

Is there a way to execute a callback if any of these commands return an exit status other than 0?

If this is not possible with bash. how about php? Can I

```
function exec_with_callback ($comd) {

    shell_exec($comd);
    callback();

}

exec_with_callback("comdA");
exec_with_callback("comdB");
...
but in parallel?
```

If no, what other language can I use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258387/bash-ampersand-operator

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your commands in loop and save the process_ids using `$!` shell variable which gives you the process id of last background job.

```
n=0
commands=(comdA  comdB comdC comdD)  #storing all 10 commands  in an array. store the status of each execution in another array
for cmd in ${commands[@]}; do
  ${cmd} &
  pid=$!
  pidarray[$n]=${pid}
  ((n+=1))
done
```

Wait for all your processes to complete using `wait <PID>` in a loop.

```
n=0
for pid in ${pidarray[@]}; do
  wait ${pid}
  exit_status_array[$n]=$?
  ((n+=1))
done
```

Now Loop through the `exit_status_array` and callback the corresponding command if exit status was other than 0

```
n=0
for s in ${exit_status_array[@]}; do
  if [[ ${s} -ne 0 ]]; then
   commands[$n] &    #callback
  fi
  ((n+=1))
done
```

You can repeat the process indefinitely if you want by using this logic and calling a function etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function check () {
    $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
    echo $?
}

command=("curl -sSL google.com" "echo 1" 'ping localhost -c 1' 'ls' 'false')

for ((i=0;i<${#command[@]};i++)); do
    echo "Command \"${command[$i]}\" returned value $(check "${command[$i]}")"
    if (($(check "${command[$i]}") != 0)); then second=1; fi
done

if ((second == 1)); then
    echo "I must run second group of commands because something have not worked!"
    echo 2
else
    echo "All is gone without issues! Goodbye $USER!"
    exit 0
fi
```

check function run command and return exit status, commands are into command array and with for loop we can see all the commands runned and their exit status. If someone have exit status not equal to zero a variable help us to run a if when all commands are finished with others commands.

**Example of output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash example
Command "curl -sSL google.com" returned value 0
Command "echo 1" returned value 0
Command "ping localhost -c 1" returned value 0
Command "ls" returned value 0
Command "false" returned value 1
I must run second group of commands because something have not worked!
2
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash example
Command "curl -sSL google.com" returned value 0
Command "echo 1" returned value 0
Command "ping localhost -c 1" returned value 0
Command "ls" returned value 0
Command "true" returned value 0
All is gone without issues! Goodbye darby!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a file `myCommands` containing a command by line :

```
echo "curl -sSL google.com" > myCommands.txt
echo "echo 1"               >> myCommands.txt
echo "ping localhost -c 1"  >> myCommands.txt
echo "ls"                   >> myCommands.txt
echo "false"                >> myCommands.txt
```

and then use xargs, and check return code of xargs.

```
xargs --arg-file myCommands.txt --max-procs 5 -I COMMAND sh -c "COMMAND"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "All command have sucessfully finish with retrun code 0" && echo "You need check the result"
```

If the code return equal 0 ==> all commands in `myCommands` file have sucessfully finish with return code 0

`--max-procs` : Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If
              max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible
              at a time.